# How can you get input from two separate microphones simultaneously with python

Tags: python, ubuntu, microphone

I am trying to get input from two separate microphones at the same time to monitor which direction sounds are coming from. I tried [this](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/64439/pyaudio-recording-from-multiple-microphones) but only one mic is being read accurately. I've searched endlessly but cannot find an answer. I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 0):

Hate to be the bearer of bad news, but unless both microphones are on the same hardware device, you are not going to be able to achieve what you want.

The audio signals from a sound device are not synchronized to the system clock, they have some built in latency, which is not exposed to calling applications, often not even to the OS itself. Unless you characterize those latencies, which are not consistent from boot to boot or even minute to minute, you'll have no idea if a 5ms offset on your mics is due to positioning or hardware latency.

The answer in your linked question is going to be your answer here as well.

Comment: The latency is fine for my purposes. But when I try to get input from two mics now one works and the other doesn't.